# Increasing power of a standalone circuit board

Tags: transistors, frequency, output, emf

I am a rookie at potentially upgrading some electronics and wanted to see if I could get a little direction on a potential first project.

I purchased a small frequency generator and would like to increase the output power. First impressions in my mind are to add an upgraded output coil and increase the voltage that is supplied to it.

Would an external copper coil potentially achieve the desired result? If so, should I attempt to tie the coil in where the original circuit runs and change the transistors somehow?

[image: Frequency Generator Board]

I'm very eager to learn some of the concepts in this field and would appreciate any feedback about this potential upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 7.83 Hz, a small magnetic dipole, the coil you see on this card, is extremely inefficient. The superpowers usually use 10s of km of overhead line together with a ground return to make an antenna to use these low frequencies.

Get an audio amplifier, one that is specified to go down to a few Hz, or one that you can modify to use larger coupling capacitors - hint, a bridged output will not need output coupling capacitors, so you will only have to attend to any input and feedback coupling. Then use it to drive the largest loop you can legally deploy.

While this smells a bit of pseudoscience, and may attract some bad reactions, [Schumann Resonances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schumann_resonances) are a thing, but perhaps not a very useful thing, or particularly (given the 10s of km for good efficiencies) accessible to amateurs on the transmit side.